# Panel visible only after resizing [Java]

Tags: java, swing

I got weird problem with my code. I got same problem earlier so I did the project from scratch, but same problem happens again.

I set the panel to not visible, but I do not know why I cannot display a new panels without resizing a app.

Main.java : https://pastebin.com/SPt5bqpF

UI.java : https://pastebin.com/HawM8CTd

Variables.java : https://pastebin.com/QvPPALkU

Code where I have a bug:

```
public void classAttitudes(){
    
    variables.classesTitleLabel.setVisible(false);
    variables.classesTitlePanel.setVisible(false);
    variables.continueClassPanel.setVisible(false);

    variables.titleAttitudePanel = new JPanel();

    variables.titleAttitudePanel.setBounds(50,50,100,100);
    variables.con.add(variables.titleAttitudePanel);

}
```

Comment: I think it is obvious. When you do `resize()` UI is updated. After manual modification you have to run `repaint()` on your own, otherwise system will not know about this updated.

Comment: But the question is why it change size? I mean i dont change size etc.  I just move full screen and go back. I dont know why at start it invisible.

Comment: Commenting because I suspect you won't like the answer: don't use absolute positioning. Use a layout manager (like GridBagLayout), which will save you from problems like this, as well as preventing problems with i18n, manual resizing and cross platform look.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public void classAttitudes() {
    variables.classesTitleLabel.setVisible(false);
    variables.classesTitlePanel.setVisible(false);
    variables.continueClassPanel.setVisible(false);

    variables.titleAttitudePanel = new JPanel();

    variables.titleAttitudePanel.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
    variables.con.add(variables.titleAttitudePanel);
    
    // ADD MANUAL REPAINT TO THE FRAME !!!
    variables.window.repaint();
}
```

***P.S.** When you resize you manin window (i.e. `JFrame`) an action is thrown and at the end of this action `repaint()` is invoke to repaint this frame with all content from UI thread (I do not remember it's name)*

Comment: Thanks for help.I am begginer at this and I didnt knew repaint()  before.Thanks

Comment: @PawełŁukasz, It may solve the stated problem but this is still incorrect design that will lead to multiple problems in the future. You should NOT be creating a panel and setting its bounds. The next time the method executes you will create a second panel and display it at exactly the same location. So you will be painting two panels, then three, then four etc. In fact Swing paints components in the reverse order they are added. So you won't even see the last panel added since the first panel added will paint over it. So the real issue is NOT the repaint() but the design of your code.

Comment: Also you should be using a layout manager. When you add components dynamically using a layout manager then you need to invoke revalidate() and repaint(). But based on the 6 lines of code posted we can't offer a proper solution.

Comment: @camickr Yes, you're right. In one word - all project should be redesigned. It's too long to explain. My solution just solves a concrete this problem, but not the others.